# pywin32 ModuleNotFoundError in python3 docx script

Tags: python, docx, pywin32

When running a python3 script that generates a word document on a windows machine the following error occurs:

```
08:53:23  Traceback (most recent call last):
08:53:23    File "c:\python\venv\py3-32-report-generator\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 236, in GetModuleForCLSID
08:53:23      __import__(sub_mod_name)
08:53:23  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com.gen_py.00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x4.ListTemplates'
```

The error only occurs once in a while, thats what confuses me so much.

It reminded me of a similar AttributeError that could be resolved by deleting the gen_py folder in ../AppData/Local/Temp/. Unfortunately this fix doesnt seem to help here.

If you need any more info describing the problem let me know. Thanks:)